# Java draw line with textures

Tags: java, awt, textures, java-2d

I'm trying to figure this out with no success. I can draw rectangles with a texture but how could I draw a line of say 4 pixels wide at an angle using a texture?   Example like a `/` or `\`?

Comment: You might be looking for `Graphics2D.setPaint(TexturePaint)` 1) [`Graphics2D.setPaint(Paint)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setPaint%28java.awt.Paint%29) 2) [`TexturePaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html)

Comment: Fine but why vote it down? I've searched for a solution here and can't find one. Others would probably like to know how to do this.

Comment: The only person notified of that comment was me, and I don't know why the question was voted down, sorry. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [TexturePaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html).

```
TexturePaint paint = new TexturePaint(bufferedImage, anchorRect);
g.setPaint(paint);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0F);
```